# How to retrieve data from mysql database connected to visual studio?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I programming with ASP.NET 4.0 MVC 3 and I decide to use MySql as my database. I have VS2010 Ultimate ,MySql 5.5.15 , Connector/Net 6.3.5 and Windows 7 / 32bit .I configured all setting to connect my application to MySql and it worked properly. When I Create some Object from my model , it is automatically insert to my table (Table's name is the same as Model's name). I can pass this query to MySql Command Line Client and I successfully receive expected result :
SELECT * FROM tableName

But I want to know if it is possible to retrieve data stored in my database from Visual Studio Data Connections. When I right-click on Table and click "Retrieve Data" , Its generate this query :

```
SELECT   ID, FirstName, LastName, Title, Tel, Username, Password, Role, Credit,IsLogin
FROM     def.mvctest.members
```

and after that show this error message :

```
SQL Execution Error :
Executed SQL statement : SELECT   ID, FirstName, LastName, Title, Tel, Username,Password, Role, Credit,IsLogin  FROM  def.mvctest.members
Error Source : MySql.Data
Error Message :you have an error in sql syntax check your manual that corresponds to your mysql server Version for the right syntax near '.members' line 1.
```

I also changed the query to "SELECT   ID, FirstName, LastName, Title, Tel, Username ,Password , Role, Credit,IsLogin  FROM  members" but again I have this error message.

I really appreciate it if anyone help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the connector is adding "def" before the database name. Just install the [latest connector](ftp://mirror.services.wisc.edu/mirrors/mysql/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.4.3.msi) and problem should go away. Install [.net FrameWork 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17851) before that, if you haven't already.